# Can move mouse but not click, in *host*, with VirtualBox VM running

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, virtual-machine, mouse

I am working on setting up a Debian Buster VM in VirtualBox, using the non-graphical installer. My host also runs Debian Buster. After I had my VM open for some time, I was still able to move my mouse, but could not click.

My keyboard also still worked. I made sure the mouse and keyboard were uncaptured. Unplugging and replugging the mouse did not help.

I'm pretty sure that both auto capture keyboard and mouse pointer integration were on in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

After closing the VM using the keyboard (Host+Q, Alt+S, Enter), mouse clicks immediately started working again. I have re-opened the VM, and my mouse clicks are still working.

I'm still not really sure what the root cause is, however.